# Count elements in a loop

Tags: php, arrays, string, loops

I'm trying to count elements in a loop to break each number of elements and show in groups

My little script

```
$data="house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*";

$exp_filter = explode("*", trim($data));
for ($x = 0; $x <= count($exp_filter); $x++)
{
    print "".$exp_filter[$x]."";
    if ($x%5 == 0)
    {
        print "<br>";   
    }

}
```

As you can see in the little script each 5 rounds I want show the tag 
 for break and show as in groups of elements.

The problem it´s always show in the first line one element and after this the rest, and no works fine.

Comment: $x%5 maybe returns 0 if $x is 0. Try this: if($x > 0 && $x%5==0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index of `$exp_filter` starts at 0, so this block of code

```
if ($x % 5 == 0)
{
    print "<br>";   
}
```

should be

```
if (($x+1) % 5 == 0)
{
    print "<br>";   
}
```

Here's the complete modified code

```
$data = "house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*";

$exp_filter = explode("*", trim($data));
for ($x = 0; $x <= count($exp_filter); $x++)
{
    print "".$exp_filter[$x]."";
    if (($x + 1) % 5 == 0)
    {
        print "<br>";   
    }
}
```

Working example: http://codepad.org/iEsKK98M

Comment: But with the last element won't throw an out of bound index array?

Comment: No, since there's no `$exp_filter[$x+1]` anywhere inside the `for` loop.

Comment: @MarcoMura Nope, the value is not used as an array key

Answer (score 1):

```
$data="house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*";

$exp_filter=explode("*",trim($data));
for($x=1;$x<=count($exp_filter);$x++)
{
  print "".$exp_filter[$x]."";
  if($x%5==0) 
  {
    print "<br>";   
  }
}
```

Try this. The problem is you started at 0 in for, you should start from 1 ;)

Comment: No work me , the first element no show , i try also this and the problem it´s the first elemt in the array with [0] no show if put 1 and no 0 and if put 0 also have problems :(

Comment: so where do you want the first element to be? do you want it to be 6 elements in the first line then 5 or 5 elements and the last one sigle? How?

Answer (score 1):

**Quickfix**:

[`Demo`](http://ideone.com/kE5slP)

```
<?php

$data="house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*";

$exp_filter=explode("*",trim($data));
for($x=1;$x<=count($exp_filter);$x++)
{
print "".$exp_filter[$x]."";
if($x > 0 && $x%5==0) 
{
echo "<br />";   
}

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use array chunk and implode instead:

```
$data="house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*house*";

foreach(array_chunk(explode('*', $data), 5) as $chunk){
    echo implode(' ', $chunk) . '<br>';
}
```

Live example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/ED2wHR